# Spring Kafka difference between ContainerProperties(TopicPartitionOffset... topicPartitions) and ContainerProperties(String... topics)

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am creating a new `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` using a `ContainerProperties`.

- Using `ContainerProperties(String... topics)`, the Consumer Group looks fine: `"state": "STABLE", "isSimpleConsumerGroup": false`
- Using `ContainerProperties(TopicPartitionOffset... topicPartitions)`, the Consumer Groups is not automatically created. It is finally created when a message is sent but the Consumer Group doesn't look fine: `"state": "EMPTY", "isSimpleConsumerGroup": true`

What's the difference between them, did I miss something. I am expecting to have the same result using the two different `ContainerProperties` constructors.

```
ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties(tpo.toArray(new TopicPartitionOffset[tpo.size()]));
containerProps.setGroupId(name);

// ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties("poc-topic1",
// "poc-topic2", "poc-topic3");
// containerProps.setGroupId(name);

containerProps.setMessageListener(new TopicMessageListener(name));

DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Serializable> factory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                Utils.get().getConsumerProperties());
container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(factory, containerProps);
// container.setAutoStartup(true);
// container.setBeanName(name);
// container.checkGroupId();

container.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct. The topic subscription causes a consumer group and their partitions distribution between group members.

When you do explicit partition assignment, not consumer group is involved at all.

See more in Apache Kafka docs: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#consumer-groups

And respective JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Manually assign a list of partitions to this consumer. This interface does not allow for incremental assignment
 * and will replace the previous assignment (if there is one).
 * <p>
 * If the given list of topic partitions is empty, it is treated the same as {@link #unsubscribe()}.
 * <p>
 * Manual topic assignment through this method does not use the consumer's group management
 * functionality. As such, there will be no rebalance operation triggered when group membership or cluster and topic
 * metadata change. Note that it is not possible to use both manual partition assignment with {@link #assign(Collection)}
 * and group assignment with {@link #subscribe(Collection, ConsumerRebalanceListener)}.
 * <p>
 * If auto-commit is enabled, an async commit (based on the old assignment) will be triggered before the new
 * assignment replaces the old one.
 *
 * @param partitions The list of partitions to assign this consumer
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException If partitions is null or contains null or empty topics
 * @throws IllegalStateException If {@code subscribe()} is called previously with topics or pattern
 *                               (without a subsequent call to {@link #unsubscribe()})
 */
@Override
public void assign(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
```

and:

```
/**
 * Subscribe to the given list of topics to get dynamically assigned partitions.
 * <b>Topic subscriptions are not incremental. This list will replace the current
 * assignment (if there is one).</b> It is not possible to combine topic subscription with group management
 * with manual partition assignment through {@link #assign(Collection)}.
 *
 * If the given list of topics is empty, it is treated the same as {@link #unsubscribe()}.
 *
 * <p>
 * This is a short-hand for {@link #subscribe(Collection, ConsumerRebalanceListener)}, which
 * uses a no-op listener. If you need the ability to seek to particular offsets, you should prefer
 * {@link #subscribe(Collection, ConsumerRebalanceListener)}, since group rebalances will cause partition offsets
 * to be reset. You should also provide your own listener if you are doing your own offset
 * management since the listener gives you an opportunity to commit offsets before a rebalance finishes.
 *
 * @param topics The list of topics to subscribe to
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException If topics is null or contains null or empty elements
 * @throws IllegalStateException If {@code subscribe()} is called previously with pattern, or assign is called
 *                               previously (without a subsequent call to {@link #unsubscribe()}), or if not
 *                               configured at-least one partition assignment strategy
 */
@Override
public void subscribe(Collection<String> topics) {
```

Comment: Ok, thanks I see the difference now, my goal would be to create a new container which will subscribe a topic and will also be assigned to a specific offset (I have topics with only one partition). Is that possible without using ```seek()``` method of ```KafkaConsumer```?

Comment: That's not. As long as you join an existing group, you only start from the stored offset. To seek to the specific one you really have to `seek()`.